# Find the longest sub array where the distance between the elements is not bigger than one

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have this array, for example: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

So the array that I want is [1,1,2], I wrote this code:

```
def Comparison(arr, n):

    i = 0
    ct = 0
    print("call")
    while i + len(arr)-n <= len(arr):
        print(arr[i:len(arr)-n+i])
        if max(arr[i:len(arr)-n+i]) - min(arr[i:len(arr)-n+i]) == 1:
            print("change at: "+str(n))
            ct = 1
            break
        i += 1
    if ct == 0:
        l = arrComparison(arr, n+1)
        return l
    else:
        return n

def longestSubarray(arr):

    menor = min(arr)
    mayor = max(arr)
    n = 0
    if mayor - menor > 1:
        n = arrComparison(arr, 1)

    return len(arr) - n
```

Where the function "LongestSubarray" just test if the longest subarray is not the array itself, and if it not, them call the other one, which is moving along the array step by step and the "n" represents the quantity of numbers that are not being selected in the subarray,, i.e. when n=2 the subarrays are going to be:

```
[1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]
```

And them when it found the first one just break and return the n.
This actually solve the question, but it does in a terrible long time, So I'd like for a more optimized way.

Comment: Seems this problem might be solved in linear time using two-pointer method (left and right indices around "good range")

Comment: Are the values always increasing or can it also decrease?

Comment: That was just for this example, the values can be placed in any way, even all the elements the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorial solution with numpy. Basically, it compares the array with itself (the complexity is thus quadratic) to compute the differences and then finds the longest stretch below threshold from the diagonal:

```
import numpy as np
def longest(arr, n=1):
    # ensure numpy array
    arr = np.array(arr)
    # calculate absolute diff matrix with itself on upper triangle
    # make boolean based on diff > threshold
    diffs = (np.argmax(np.c_[np.triu(np.abs(arr-arr[:,None])>n),
                             np.ones(len(arr)) # this handles the case where array is uniform
                            ],
                      axis=1)
             -np.arange(len(arr)) # subtract position of diagonal
            )
    # get position of first non matching value (value is length of stretch)
    m = np.argmax(diffs)
    return arr[m:m+diffs[m]].tolist()
```

examples:

```
>>> longest([1,1,2,3,4,5]) 
[1, 1, 2]

>>> longest([1,1,2,3,4,5], n=2) 
[1, 1, 2, 3]

>>> longest([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

>>> longest([9, 8, 7, 6, 7])
[7, 6, 7]

>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> longest(np.random.randint(0, 50, size=10000), n=2)
[49, 47, 49, 49, 47]
```

Comment: This has quadratic complexity? Because we need to compute the square matrix of differences.

Comment: @Stef you're absolutely right. I initially provided this answer for "fun" as there were already other answers with loops, but those later proved to be incorrect. I also provided an [answer with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69069994/16343464) and it runs faster.

Comment: You should probably mention the quadratic complexity in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a 'two-pointer' approach in linear time: move along the list, keeping left and right pointers around your current array. If our array has a distance that's too large, move left towards right; otherwise, move right forward. Track the elements inside the current array with a dict.

```py
def longest_subarray(arr):
    if not arr:
        return []

    left = 0
    best_length = 1
    best_start = 0
    counts = {arr[0]: 1}

    for right in range(1, len(arr)):
        counts[arr[right]] = counts.get(arr[right], 0) + 1
        if len(counts) <= 2 and max(counts)-min(counts) <= 1:
            best_start = left
            best_length = right-left+1
            continue
        counts[arr[left]] -= 1
        if counts[arr[left]] == 0:
            del counts[arr[left]]
        left += 1
    return arr[best_start: best_start+best_length]
```

Comment: What do we expect if the array is A = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4] ?

Comment: @DanielHao It depends on the problem description; with multiple valid answers, you should be able to return any of them if no other instructions are given. This code will always give the leftmost longest subarray, by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an imperative working version.

It works by looping a first index (`i`) and for each subarray (`i` to the end of the array (minus length of current longest to optimize)), finds if there is a longer subarray matching the condition:

```
def longest(array, n=1):
    pos_longest = 0
    len_longest = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(array)-len_longest+1:
        length = 0
        for j in range(i+1,len(array)-1):
            if abs(array[j]-array[i])>n:
                break
            else:
                length = j-i+1
        if length>len_longest:
            pos_longest = i
            len_longest = length

        i+=1
    return array[pos_longest:pos_longest+len_longest]
```

examples:

```
>>> longest([1,1,2,3,4,5]) 
[1, 1, 2]

>>> longest([1,1,2,3,4,5], n=2) 
[1, 1, 2, 3]

>>> longest([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

>>> longest([9, 8, 7, 6, 7])
[7, 6, 7]

>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> longest(np.random.randint(0, 50, size=10000), n=2)
[49, 47, 49, 49, 47]
```

Answer (score -3):

You can simplify the process by using itertools.combinations. You start with the largest possible combination and work your way down.

```
from itertools import combinations

arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(arr),1,-1):
    for el in combinations(arr,i):
        if max(el) - min(el) == 1: break
    else:
       continue
    break

print(el)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 2)
```

Edit: If you only want continuous subsets, here is a simple modification.

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = len(arr)
for i in range(n,1,-1):
    for el in combinations(arr,i):
        if (max(el)-min(el)==1  and
        any([*el]==arr[j:j+len(el)] for j in range(0,n-len(el)+1))): break
    else:
       continue
    break
```

Comment: Wrong answer. Apart from weird effectiveness, combinations select subsets of elements while **subarray** assumes **continuous range**