# Need help in Python hackerrank problem solving

Tags: python, list, data-structures

So, I am stuck on a question and I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my code.

*Question is-* Given an array of integers, find the longest subarray where the absolute difference between any two elements is less than or equal to .
Example `a = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5]`
There are two subarrays meeting the criterion:  and .
The maximum length subarray has  elements.
`[1,1,2,2]` and `[4,4,5,5,5]`

*Returns*
int: **the length of the longest subarray that meets the criterion**

or visit the link [Hackerrank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=false)

```py
def pickingNumbers(a):
    a.sort()
    answer = 0
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(a)-1,1,-1):
        count = 0
        temp = [list(l) for l in list(itertools.combinations(a,i))]
        for j in temp:
            for k in range(len(j)-1):
                if abs( j[k+1] - j[k] ) <= 1:
                    count +=1
            if count == len(j):
                answer = len(j)
                break
```

Comment: Have you seen [this thread on the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068728/find-the-longest-sub-array-where-the-distance-between-the-elements-is-not-bigger/69069903#69069903)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the statement asks you to to find a subarray, not subsequence. A subarray is a continuous chain of elements from the parent array. Here by sorting the array you are destroying the parent array's order whenever the array given to you is ascending. Hence your program will give wrong output

Comment: So should I try making subarrays myself or combination object will do?

Comment: Don't sort the array in the beginning, and iterate two loops for i and j from 1 to n to make subarrays.

Comment: Sorting is not a wrong thing to do. The constraints say that the length of "two" numbers that abs diff <= 1. So in a given two numbers You can either sort or not sort it is only a  preference.